# Vuex, не могу получить данные из store.state?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Как мне получить данные из productName, если я получаю Observer

**comp.vue**

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        productName: this.$store.state.products
    }
```

**store.js**

```
export default {
state: {
    products: [],
    productName: []
},
mutations: {
    LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS(state, payload) {
        state.products = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    async loadAllProducts({commit}) {
        try {
            let res = await Vue.axios.get('/products/')
            commit('LOAD_ALL_PRODUCTS', res.data)
        } catch(err) {
             console.log(err)
        }
    }
},
getters: {
    getProducts: state => state.products,
```

выдает:

```
mounted() {
    console.log(this.productName);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем проблема то ?

Comment: Делаю выпадающий список с v-autocomplete, с name разобрался выпадает список с товарами, нужно как то id этого товара и по выбору перейти на продукт

Answer (score 0):

Для этого стоит использовать `computed`.

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        /* ... */
    }
},

computed: {
    products: function () {
        return this.$store.state.products
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял )